# VSCode extension: embed standard language in mine

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to embed standard languages (for example `JavaScript`) in my language extension. This means I want to see autocompletes, syntax higlighting etc. as in `file.js`. Can I do this (how)?

Thank you for any examples!

Answer (score 11):

You can continue `abc-lang` example in [Embedded Languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#embedded-languages) guide with additional grammar `syntaxes/abc.tmLanguage.json`:

````
{
    "scopeName": "source.abc",
    "patterns": [ { "include": "#expression" } ],
    "repository": {
        "expression": {
            "patterns": [
                { "include": "#letter" },
                { "include": "#paren-expression" },
                { "include": "#code" }
            ]
        },
        "letter": {
            "match": "a|b|c",
            "name": "keyword.letter"
        },
        "paren-expression": {
            "begin": "\\(",
            "end": "\\)",
            "beginCaptures": {
                "0": { "name": "punctuation.paren.open" }
            },
            "endCaptures": {
                "0": { "name": "punctuation.paren.close" }
            },
            "name": "expression.group",
            "patterns": [ { "include": "#expression" } ]
        },
        "code": {
            "begin": "```js",
            "end": "```",
            "beginCaptures": {
                "0": { "name": "punctuation.code.open" }
            },
            "endCaptures": {
                "0": { "name": "punctuation.code.close" }
            },
            "name": "meta.embedded.block.javascript",
            "patterns": [ { "include": "source.js" } ]
        }
    }
}
````

Permalink for Matt's comment is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5712574281bb096a2dd4ceda7e266d507f775b45/extensions/html/syntaxes/html.tmLanguage.json#L1936

Comment: As it confused me for a minute for others arriving here; 'source.js' isn't a filename, it's the name of the javascript grammar.

Comment: Continuing from BJury, the name `source.js` is defined in `"$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\package.json"`.

Answer (score 9):

Syntax highlighting is easy, just include the top level scope of the language to be embeded. Html [for example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/html/syntaxes/html.tmLanguage.json#L330) uses `"include": "source.js"` to add js syntax highlighting inside script blocks.

IntelliSense is considerably more difficult. Again, take a look at [what vscode's  HTML extension does](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/html-language-features/server/src/modes/javascriptMode.ts). It basically splits html files into virtual documents (one for script blocks, one for style blocks, one for html) and then embeds the required language libraries for each of these languages to provide IntelliSense. The [Vetur extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur) also does something similar. In both cases, the extensions owns the top level document (html or vue) and then delegate to the correct embedded language based on where IntelliSense requests are made

Comment: thanks. this is helpful, I couldn't figure out how to do the syntax highlighting part. I could include it with contributions property of package.json (which gives you the autocomplete features, although not all of them). However the `for example` ref has link rot, the line number linked to is no longer in the same location. Trivial, first world problems, just thought I would let you know it might be helpful to include a code snippet with your answer. thanks!